# Place to get free live Forex quotes via API?

Tags: programming, data, fx

Are any free Forex data APIs available?  There are a ton of historical data repositories that are freely available but what about a live, streaming data API?  1 minute updates or tick data would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options for real-time tick data are limited, but there are some:

- Limited pairs, multiple updates per minute (HTML format) http://webrates.truefx.com/rates/connect.html?f=html
- The only reliable/free JSON API: http://1forge.com/forex-data-api

Answer (score 2):

There is a new currency API I have seen by https://fxmarketapi.com it's free and real-time for even a basic version.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to open a trading account, the choice of brokers is huge. Some of them even offer next to their own API also FIX protocol. Minimal deposit could be as low as couple of hundred dollars, datafeed is then free.

Not free but affordable are dedicated datafeeds, about forty dollars per months.

Comment: Examples of brokers are interactivebrokers.com and thinkorswim.com. What are examples of "dedicated datafeeds for about \$40 a month"? Maybe barchart.com, any others?

Comment: I wanted to avoid anything looking as an advertisement here, but never mind. Brokers Pepperstone and FXCM provide FIX (with integral a.k.a. truefx.com and own ticks, respectively). IQFeed is a datafeed (with FXCM ticks), you might want to visit futures.io for further feed hints and an affiliate discount. Tenfore is more expensive but consolidates more liquidity providers.

Answer (score 0):

For real-time prices: http://1forge.com/forex-data-api.

For historical data: http://datadt.com.

Both sources are free.

Update: datadt.com seems dead for some good time. Domain up for sale...

Answer (score 0):

Real-time forex and crypto (ticks and bars (21 periods from 1 minute to 1 month)):
https://cerebro1.com

It provides also technical indicators values live.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it myself (yet) but

https://fcsapi.com/

looks promising